# Mapping an object data into table columns using React

Tags: html, reactjs

I want the following object array to be mapped into table columns using react...The table contains 4 columns and these values should be mapped into them ...and there are two rows as well.....

```
 <table>
                <tbody>
                        [{
                            voucherCode: 'DC12',
                            product: 'TEST PRODUCT',
                            startDate:'10-05-2019',
                            endDate:'06-10-2019'
                        },
                        {
                            voucherCode: 'DC123',
                            product: 'TEST PRODUCT',
                            startDate:'10-05-2019',
                            endDate:'06-10-2019'
                        }
                        {/* ].map( ( {name, email} ) => {

                            return <td key={email}>{name} - {email}</td>
                        }) */}
                        ].map( ( {eBird, index} ) => {
                            return(
                                <tr>
                                    <td >{voucherCode} </td>
                                    </tr>

                            )


                        })


                </tbody> 
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is close. In the `map` function you'll want to destructure the keys of the object and render a column for each of those. Since it looks like there are four fixed columns it's probably easiest to explicitly list those out (as opposed to doing something dynamic and iterating over the keys of the object).

The updates to the original code you posted:

- Missing curly braces around the array literal and map `{[ ... ].map()}`.
- The commented out code is wrapped in curly braces and isn't valid. Since it seems unused, I would suggest removing it entirely.
- Updated the values being destructed to match the actual objects. `eBird` doesn't appear to be defined in any of the objects.

```js
function Table() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {[
          {
            voucherCode: "DC12",
            product: "TEST PRODUCT",
            startDate: "10-05-2019",
            endDate: "06-10-2019"
          },
          {
            voucherCode: "DC123",
            product: "TEST PRODUCT",
            startDate: "10-05-2019",
            endDate: "06-10-2019"
          }
        ].map(({ voucherCode, product, startDate, endDate }) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{voucherCode}</td>
              <td>{product}</td>
              <td>{startDate}</td>
              <td>{endDate}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```